# Create Ranges in the list

Tags: c#, list, range, price, enumerable

I have a Price list as

```
10
21
30
90
100
150
400
```

I want to add prices in 10 increments below 100. Above 100 to display in increments of 100

So my final price list would be like

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
200
300
400
```

Has anyone has done something similar to this. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you intend to do with `21` and `150` from the original list?  Just throw them away?

Comment: This is unclear, what about the original values?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of lack of clarity on whether you want to generate 'n' elements or whether you want to generate till the max value in the list.

**Case 1 : If Generate till Max Value in List**

```
public IEnumerable<int> Generate(int maxValue)
{
    var currentValue = 0;
    while(currentValue<maxValue)
    {
        currentValue += currentValue < 100 ? 10:100;
        yield return currentValue;
    }
}
```

You can now use the method as

```
var myList = new List<int>(new int[] { 12, 21, 30, 90, 100, 150, 404 });
var result = Generate(myList.Max());
```

**Case 2 : When you want to generate N Elements.**

```
var initialValue = 0;
var list = Enumerable.Range(1,totalNumberOfExpectedItems)
                     .Select(x=> 
                       { 
                          initialValue = initialValue < 100 ? initialValue + 10 : initialValue + 100; 
                          return initialValue;
                       })
```

[Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) aids in generating sequence in a specified range

For `totalNumberOfExpectedItems = 13`,

Output

```
10 
20 
30 
40 
50 
60 
70 
80 
90 
100 
200 
300 
400
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following program works as you desire:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace csharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var prices = new int[]{10, 21, 30, 90, 100, 150, 400}.ToList();
            var finalPriceList =
                Enumerable
                .Range(0, 10)
                .Select(i => prices.Min() + 10 * i)
                .TakeWhile(i => i < Math.Min(100, prices.Max()))
                .Concat(
                    Enumerable
                    .Range(1, 1000)
                    .Select(i => 100 * i)
                    .TakeWhile(i => i <= prices.Max())
                ).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", finalPriceList));
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

I am assuming you are getting all values between the lowest and highest values in the list.

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>(new int[] { 12, 21, 30, 90, 100, 150, 404 });
int max = myList.Max() - myList.Max() % 100;
int min = myList.Min() - myList.Min() % 10;

int tmp = (int)Math.Round(Math.Log10(min), MidpointRounding.ToZero);
List<int> newList = new List<int>();
for (int a = tmp, b = min / (int)Math.Pow(10, tmp); (Math.Pow(10, a) * b <= max); )
{
     newList.Add((int)(Math.Pow(10, a) * b));
     if (b < 9) b++;
     else
     {
         b = 1;
         a++;
     }
}

//newList : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```